# How to embed and query BsonDocuments as Enumerable types in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to embeding and query Bsondocuments as Enumerables types like IList to create denormalized tables using official C# driver with automatic get and set methods. Thanks.

```
public class Content
{
    public Content()
    {
        ID = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ID
...
public IList<MongoDBRef> ContentDetail  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to extend `MongoDBRef` in your project with a generic based class like `MyDBRef<T>`,
in that class you can create some methods and properties like `bool IsLoaded`, or `T Load(MongoDatabase db)`, etc.... And you won't need to use `MongoDBRef` in your project, I think is handy, at least it is for me.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to query late in one step to get all content.

'Embedded' means that the child document is stored within a parent document. If the document is *embedded*, then it will return in one query. Simply query for the parent.

So the answer appears to be within your question. You may need to elaborate your question.